# Missing application launcher after deployment

Tags: android, android-manifest

This week I got my new Samsung S3 and wanted to deploy a project to my phone.
After deploying it with Eclipse it starts up normally and works.

But I then can't find a launcher in the main menu. :-/ (Last time I rebooted the device and then it was there, but I think that's not a solution)

In Settings - Application Manager - Installed Applications I can find the application.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Android 4.0.4
Eclipse Indigo
Latest SDK installed

Here is my android manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.uniba.wiai.ktr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ktr"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:logo="@drawable/ktr" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".KTRStreamServiceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="KTRStreamConfiguration"></activity>
        <service android:name="KTRStreamService" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:exported="false">
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>

Thanks
```

Added:

Tested the tool with a Nexus (also Android 4.0.4) and it works.

Comment: is it right `android:debuggable="true" ?`

Comment: what is android:logo="@drawable/ktr"?

Comment: @Samir Mangroliya: android:debuggable="true" ?  -> i got this from here http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html to receive more debugging information.

Comment: @Dipak Keshariya: What is `code`android:logo="@drawable/ktr"? -> ktr is a .png-File for the logo.

Comment: In http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size there are some DPI values. Does your Logo match thouse?

Answer (score 0):

Same of this problem happend to me in past, and the problem was in the `Application Icon Size` try to make it smaller and in Square ratio( follow icon design guideline in android website).

---

some third party launchers ignores applications with wrong icon size.

Comment: Checked it: got 96x96 (xhdpi), 72x72 (hdpi), 48x48 (mdpi), 36x36 (ldpi) :-/